# Django rest-framwork [views]: users can update only modules they created

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

So I have a view for my Django app that is used to update/delete user profiles. I'm wondering is there a better way to check if the person who's requesting the change is the same one that's in the url.

request url looks like this `/profile/<str:username>`

```py
class UserDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializerFull
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = "username"

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(request.user) == kwargs.get("username"):
            return super().put(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(
            data={"msg": "unauthorized request"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(request.user) == kwargs.get("username"):
            return super().patch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(
            data={"msg": "unauthorized request"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(request.user) == kwargs.get("username"):
            return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(
            data={"msg": "unauthorized request"}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )
```

As all of the methods are repeating the same code is there a way to write something just for once and use it everywhere.

Also for other models that are made by the User profile i have the same issue as a lot of the code is repeating itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom permission class as follows:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsRequestingUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Write permissions are only allowed to the owner of the snippet.
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Use this permission class in your class:

```
class UserDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # other logic
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsRequestingUser]

    # other logic
```

For more details, you can see the [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/).

Comment: Thanks will check it out

Answer (score 1):

That's what permissions are for.

```
class IsOwner(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Something like that will do the trick but you will have to adjust it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help!